# Delay in cycle while making 3-bit up/down counter

Tags: integrated-circuit, flipflop, counter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feX7oT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to make a 3-bit up/down counter, after failing to use xor IC I resorted to AND and NOR ICs, but the result of the IC starts turning off halfway through the positive half of cycle, and also the second flip-flop only sometimes triggers. And sometimes while changing wires on the right the 555 clock on the left stops triggering (or the first flip-flop stops triggering)
From the left the ICs used are:
NE555P
HD74LS73AP
SN74HC08N
SN74HC02N
HD74LS73AP (Not connected yet)
[image: cycle start]

[image: cycle mid]

[image: cycle wnd]

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic.

Comment: @winny I believe the correct schematic has been added.

Comment: @SamilTajani Did you first simplify something like the 74169 to get your schematic? Or did you find it somewhere? Or did you construct it from a basic design process of your own? Also, one thing that always makes me sit up and worry is when I see the clocks not all driven from the same source. Your schematic looks a little 'ripple-like' for the clocks and that puts me on edge.

Comment: Tying LEDs from a "logical output" without a resistor isn't a good idea. A red LED from output to GND almost guarantees it doesn't even reach TTL *input* high level.

Comment: Umm - what *delay* does the title mention, and what is your answerable electronics question?

Comment: Missing series resistors on LEDs and decoupling capacitors.

Comment: @periblepsis yes it is an asynchronous circuit, the boolean expression for second and third clock input was A XOR B where B is the switch input and A is previous flip-flops output, since XOR wasn't working for me I changed the equation to (A NOR B) NOR (AB)

Comment: @greybeard I didn't know how to phrase the question, the first green led is output of first Flip Flop and second green led is output of agates that is meant to be clock for second flip flop, which the switch is off the second led should be the same as first led but it turns off faster which leads to problems.

Comment: @winny I understand adding resistor.but don't know what decoupling  a capacitor means, the 555 circuit was copied from a tutorial, but I added everything else on the left so did something mess it up?

Comment: *[power supply] decoupling capacitors* need to go as close to the power supply pins as feasible - I had small polar&ceramic ones in the middle of the breadboard power rails, + about one for&at every IC. **DO NOT** leave C-MOS inputs open as SW1 may be doing. (It probably isn't wired to short +6 V to GND - or is it?)

Comment: `second green LED is output of [NOR1] a gate that is meant to be the clock for the second flip flop` is not where I see LEDs (all amber) in the CircuitLab schematic.

Comment: @greybeard I have edited the schematic to show current circuit as well as the circuit I am aiming for.

Comment: Now both circuits show a switch connecting 6 V to GND.

Comment: Have you tried a search on your favorite search engine, or here even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using both HC and LS devices? It's not a good idea to connect 74LSxx outputs into 74HCxx inputs. TTL is weakly high. HC needs something more for a high to be reliable. If you must combine these families, use HCT not HC.

Moving on and assuming a U/D input being '0' means *count-up* then here's the state transitions:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\text{State} & \text{U/D=0 Next} & \text{U/D=0 Toggle} & \text{U/D=1 Next} & \text{U/D=1 Toggle}\\\\
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&1&1\\
  1&0&0\\
  1&0&1\\
  1&1&0\\
  1&1&1\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&1&1\\
  1&0&0\\
  1&0&1\\
  1&1&0\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&0\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  JK_C & JK_B & JK_A\\\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&1\\
  0&0&1\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&1\\
  0&0&1\\
  1&1&1\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&1&1\\
  1&0&0\\
  1&0&1\\
  1&1&0\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  JK_C & JK_B & JK_A\\\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&1\\
  0&0&1\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&1\\
  0&0&1\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

Nice symmetries above lead to these relatively simple k-maps:

For \$U/D=0\$ (count up):

$$\begin{array}{rl}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
JK_C&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&0&0&1&0\\
Q_C&0&0&1&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
JK_B&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&0&1&1&0\\
Q_C&0&1&1&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
JK_A&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&1&1&1&1\\
Q_C&1&1&1&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

For \$U/D=1\$ (count down):

$$\begin{array}{rl}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
JK_C&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&1&0&0&0\\
Q_C&1&0&0&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
JK_B&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&1&0&0&1\\
Q_C&1&0&0&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
JK_A&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_C}&1&1&1&1\\
Q_C&1&1&1&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

Since 74LSxx devices can sink a lot more current than they can source, wire it up like this:

[image]

It's synchronous so it will probably work a little better. I didn't try and calculate your 555 timer rate. Obviously though, keep it slow enough to perceive the counting. (Note the use of the \$\overline{Q}\$ outputs for activating the LEDs.)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it let the result be known.

Comment: BTW, how does 555 factor into this, it's not hc or ls so does it not matter? And for XOR I have a cd4070, which series will that work with?

Comment: @SamilTajani You will be fine with the 555. It's got a decent output that should work okay. There are cmos versions of the 555. They should also be fine, I believe. I'm not sure about the cd4070, though. I'd need to go read the datasheet on it.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I had to connect the inputs of xor to ground with a resistor though.

Comment: @SamilTajani Glad it worked out. Hopefully, you followed the process I followed and can do this for yourself, now.